For each vertex $v$ of a polytope $P$, is vertex $v$ the unique optimal solution to some linear program over $P$?
Is it true that for every vertex $v$ of a polytope $P$, three exists some linear programming specification with $P$ as the feasible region for which vertex $v$ is the unique optimal solution?
If this is true, where can I find a reference for it?

Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point

There is a hyperplane $H$ through $v$ such that the rest of $P$ is strictly on one side of $H$.  Your program is the linear functional defining $H$.

Are we assuming the polytope $P$ to be convex?

Convex polytopes are the only kind used in linear programming.
